# Getting POM parent in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, repository, gradle

In Gradle, I am trying to copy to my workspace, all dependencies I need for a package in the shape of a local repo. I know I can get all the files with:

```
configurations."$configName".each { file -> ... }
```

This way I can also resolve all the POMs for each artifact, but if those POMs have parents defined in them, Gradle resolves them to its local repo.

Can I access this list somehow? The files together with their POMs and parent POMs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in public API for that. You'd have to parse the POMs' `<parent>` elements (easy with Groovy), resolve the parents, and so on, until no `<parent>` elements are left.